# Workflow 2013 - Task Status and Approval Status not updating

Tags: 2013, workflow, approval, status

I wrote a simple approval workflow in 2013.

I go into the task, approve it and submit. The approval is recorded.
However, the Approval status in my documents view still shows as "Pending". The workflow task status still shows as "Not Started" and the task remains. What is going on?

Here's the code:

```
Stage:Approve New Document
    Log Workflow Started to the workflow history list
    Start a task process with Current Item:Approvers (Task outcome to Variable: Outcome3 )
    Log Workflow Ended to the workflow history list
    If Variable: Outcome3 equals Approved
        Set Workflow Status to Approved
    If Variable: Outcome3 equals Rejected
        Set Workflow Status to Rejected
Transition to stage
    Go to End of Workflow
```

Answer (score 1):

Its looks fine. Unfortunately we have no debugger for workflows so use workflow log history to check and also recheck proper arrangement of lines .

```
`Stage:Approve New Document

Log Workflow Started to the workflow history list
Set Workflow Status to Something // set initial status
Log Workflow Started to the workflow history list // check initial status
Start a task process with Current Item:Approvers (Task outcome to Variable: Outcome3 )
Log Workflow Ended to the workflow history list
If Variable: Outcome3 equals Approved
    Set Workflow Status to Approved
else 
    Set Workflow Status to Rejected
Transition to stage
Go to End of Workflow`
```

Comment: Hiya,Thanks for the confirmation. I have put the additional logging in, but it makes no difference. This workflow just does not react how you would expect. indeed, when you approve the document, in the task there are not even any buttons or anything. I just don't see any standard behavior executing in any way.

Comment: Did you set all fields in start task process correctly? ie, task content type: workflow task (sp 2013) , outcome field: task outcome . this choices of task outcome field will be displayed as buttons .